# How to run a timer on the background that updates a label in a viewmodel

Tags: android, xamarin, timer

I am trying to run a timer that updates a label every second on background (async). The timer should run from 0 to 60 min and only show {MIN:SEC} in the label. But I am having a hard time to run the timer in background that updates the label. This is what I had for so for but it won't work:

```
Timer timer;
    Stopwatch sw;
    public TimerViewModel()
    {
        Title = "Tijd";
        StartTimer();
    }

    private async void StartTimer()
    {
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.Interval = (1000);
        //timer.Elapsed += new EventHandler(UpdateLabel);
        sw = new Stopwatch();
        timer.Start();
        sw.Start();
    }

    private async void UpdateLabel()
    {
        await Task.Run(async () =>
        {

        }).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
```

MainPage:

```
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
        xmlns:views="clr-namespace:EscapeHaarlem.Views"
        x:Class="EscapeHaarlem.Views.MainPage">
<TabbedPage.Children>
    <NavigationPage Title="Tijd">
        <NavigationPage.Icon>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="FileImageSource">
                <On Platform="iOS" Value="tab_about.png"/>
            </OnPlatform>
        </NavigationPage.Icon>
        <x:Arguments>
            <views:AboutPage />
        </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>

    <NavigationPage Title="Hints">
        <NavigationPage.Icon>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="FileImageSource">
                <On Platform="iOS" Value="tab_feed.png"/>
            </OnPlatform>
        </NavigationPage.Icon>
        <x:Arguments>
            <views:ItemsPage />
        </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>
</TabbedPage.Children>
```

About page:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="EscapeHaarlem.Views.AboutPage"
         xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:EscapeHaarlem.ViewModels"
         Title="{Binding Title}">
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <vm:TimerViewModel />
</ContentPage.BindingContext>
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="12*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="6*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="6*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <StackLayout x:Name="RealTimeTimer" Grid.Column="0" VerticalOptions="Center">
        <Label Text="{Binding RealTimeTimer}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Rotation="270" FontSize="150" HorizontalOptions="Center"></Label>
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout Grid.Column="1" VerticalOptions="Center">
        <Label Text="Straftijd" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Rotation="270" FontSize="40" HorizontalOptions="End"></Label>
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout Grid.Column="2" VerticalOptions="Center">
            <Label Text="00:00" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Rotation="270" FontSize="40" HorizontalOptions="Start" ></Label>
    </StackLayout>
</Grid>
```

thanks in advance

Comment: What part is not working? Why is the EventHandler commented out?

Comment: Because the eventhandler turns out red and wont work, it wont show and update the time

Comment: @Xader By "Turns out red" do you mean a error shows up?. If it does, what does the error say.

Comment: My bad for my bad question, the error is: No overload for 'Updatelabel' matches delegate 'ElapsedEventHandler'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are wrongly assigning the event handler [as seen in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer.elapsed?view=netframework-4.8).

Change

```
timer.Elapsed += new EventHandler(UpdateLabel);
```

to

```
timer.Elapsed +=UpdateLabel; //or 
timer.Elapsed +=System.EventHandler(UpdateLabel)
```

not sure from the top of my head

And

```
private async void UpdateLabel()
```

to

```
private static void UpdateLabel(Object source, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
```

This should allow you to to trigger the Elapsed event. You problem was your confusing regular functions and event functions. You should read up on it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/events/)

Comment: Thanks! One question does this work in the background ? So as example when I try push an item in a viewmodel does the updatelabel still work? Because I thaught this only worked with async.

Comment: @Xandervandenberg Well I would need to see your whole code to give you a  complete answer but on first tough  Task.run should be done in its own thread so you shouldn't have any problems with viewmodel additions. Also if this helped you out please select it as the answer so you can close the question. Cheers..